# Cant run a swift code created in a work space of other projects written in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I created a Work Space in Xcode, and it contains projects written in objective-c. Today I created a project named FMDB and it was written in objective-c, then I deleted it from the workspace, and I created a new project with the same name but this time in Swift.

then I created a new project in that work space but it is in Swift. when i tried to compile the project, it shows me the design of the project that was in objective-c.

should I change the setting of Xcode to run a swift project created in a work space contains objective-c projects?

Comment: Did you make a bridging header?

Comment: Did you do a clean build?

Comment: @Leif would you please tell me what is the Bridging Header

Comment: @user2121 A bridging header is a file you need to have if you want to mix obj-c and swift. Google bridging header and there a quite a few resources on it.